# Android: Custom offline map using an image

Tags: android, maps, android-imageview

I'm trying to build an app that can display a map using an image stored inside the app, with most of the functionality of Google Maps but using this custom image and not having to connect in order to fetch the map tiles. The main thing I am looking for is a way of displaying an image in which the user can pinch to zoom, drag to move and click on overlays. I will also try to add overlays to the map based on lat/long coordinates and display the user's location, but this shouldn't be too hard since I can define one lat/long point on the map and calculate all others from that one. Does anyone know of anything I can use for displaying such a map?

Comment: Have you found anything appropriate?

Comment: Hi @benwad , im searching for a similar library in android ,did you come across any in your search?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look into [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) it´s a library that allows you to do exactly what you want using map from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

We are using it to have features like in "Google Map" but being offline with images loaded on an SDCard. You can use tools like [Mobac](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to create the offline atlases.

I'm just not sure if you will be able to add overlays to the map...

Comment: thanks Guillaume but I cannot use OpenStreetMap, I have to use static images which have been provided to me

Comment: hi lisa , im searching for a similar library in android ,did you come across any in your search?